# App keep crashing due to memory pressure

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, xcode-instruments

My app is saving and retrieving data from Parse.com. And showing images, buttons, scrollviews, etc.. (the normal stuff). Then when I got near finishing my app, it started to receive memory warnings and the app started crashing often. I checked it in the Instruments and noticed the live bytes was extremely high at some points, and I can't figure out why.

[image]

[image]

Is the app crashing because of the high live bytes? What should value of the live bytes be?

Obiously something is going on in the VM. But I have no idea what this is. What is the `VM: CG raster data`? And this: `VM: CG Image`? I am not using `CGImages` only `UIImages`

Comment: What is the exception printed to the console when your app crashes?

Comment: @Tommy: I already made the same edit before posting the comment…

Comment: @abarnert it didn't show here; some sort of harmless AJAX race condition I guess. Having not yet spotted your answer I assumed you were too new to have the editing privileges. I apologise to all for the wasted edit.

Comment: @Tommy: No big deal. And yeah, it was completely harmless; if you look at the edit history, it shows that you successfully did nothing. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the app crashing because of the high live bytes?

Yes.

> What should value of the live bytes be?

There's not fixed number. The limits change from OS version to OS version, and sometimes depend on the device and what else is going on at the moment. The right thing to do is (a) try not to use so much, and (b) heed the warnings and dispose of stuff you don't need.

> Obiously something is going on in the VM. But I have no idea what this is. What is the VM: CG raster data? And this: VM: CG Image? I am not using CGImages only UIImages

A [`UIImage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is just a wrapper around a `CGImage`.

You have too many images alive at the same time. That's the problem you have to fix.

So, how many is too many? It depends on how big they are.

Also, note that the "raster data" is the *decompressed* size. A 5Mpix RGBA 8bpp image takes 20MB of RAM for its raster data, whether the file is 8MB or 8KB.

---

> I still feel the number is too high though, or is 30-40 MB an okey number handling 3-6 full-screen sized images at a time? This is when tested on a 4 year old iPhone4, iOS 7. If that matters.

On an iPhone 4, "full-screen" means 640x960 pixels. 8bpp RGBA means 4 bytes per pixel. So, with 6 such images, that's 640*960*4*6 = 14MB. So, that's the absolute minimum storage you should expect if you've loaded and drawn 6 full-screen images.

So, why do you actually see more than twice that?

Well, as [Images and Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW2) in the class reference says:

> In low-memory situations, image data may be purged from a UIImage object to free up memory on the system. This purging behavior affects only the image data stored internally by the UIImage object and not the object itself. When you attempt to draw an image whose data has been purged, the image object automatically reloads the data from its original file. This extra load step, however, may incur a small performance penalty.

So think of that 14MB as basically a cache that iOS uses to speed things up, in case you want to draw the images again. If you run a little low on memory, it'll purge the cache automatically, so you don't have to worry about it.

So, that leaves you with 16-24MB, which is presumably used by the buffers of your UI widgets and layers and by the compositor behind the scenes. That's a bit more than the theoretical minimum of 14MB, but not horribly so.

If you want to reduce memory usage further, what you probably need to do is not draw all 6 images. If they're full-screen, there's no way the user can see more than 1 or 2 at a time. So, you could load and render them on demand instead of preloading them (or, if you can predict which one will usually be needed next, preload 1 of them instead of all of them), and destroy them when they're no longer visible. Since you'd then only have 2 images instead of 6, that should drop your memory usage from 16-24MB + a 14MB cache to 5-9MB + a 5MB cache. This obviously means a bit more CPU—it probably won't noticeably affect responsiveness or battery drain, but you'd want to test that. And, more importantly, it will definitely make your code more complicated.

Obviously, if it's appropriate for your images, you could also do things like using non-Retina images (which will cut memory by 75%) or dropping color depth from RGBA-8 to ARGB-1555 (50%), but most images don't look as good that way (which is why we have high-color Retina displays).

Comment: ... or he has a sensible number alive but hasn't spotted that all the images he's fetching are 5 megapixels.

Comment: @Tommy: Well, if you're trying to deal with 5Mpix images on a 3G-S, "sensible" is a much smaller number than if you're trying to deal with QVGA images on a 5s. :)

Comment: So the problem could be that the images I'm fetching form Parse.com could be too big?

Comment: @Peter: In a word, yes.

Comment: But in my first pic, with the VM: CG raster data, is that also images you think?

Comment: @Peter: I believe `CG raster data` is the decompressed images themselves, plus any extra representations you've asked for, plus the buffers that it uses for compositing images, although I'm not 100% sure on the details there.

Comment: @Peter: Have you read the ["Images and Memory Management"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) note in the docs? It isn't entirely helpful, but it does explain the basic issue.

Comment: I managed to reduce the memory usage to 30-40 MB, and stopped the memory warnings and crashes. I still feel the number is too high though, or is 30-40 MB an okey number handling 3-6 full-screen sized images at a time? This is when tested on a 4 year old iPhone4, iOS 7. If that matters.